# Ionic 3 - Dragula - CSS style being lost - mirrorContainer

Tags: angular, ionic3, dragula, ng2-dragula

I am a new developer and new to Ionic.

Trying to integrate the Dragula module and I have it working in terms of being able to re-order my elements but the CSS is being lost between drag and drop. (comes back again once you drop it).

I have read the docs and other people's questions and have narrowed it down to "drake" possibly and setting the mirrorContainer (as document.body is not working)? As the items I want to reorder are not part of the DOM on build (the get shown on expanding the list item).

As I said I'm new to all this and am having trouble figuring out where and how to write the actual code for this. Any help with written examples would be amazing.

My code below.

app.html

```
<ion-header class="toolbar-header">
  <web-nav class="web-only"></web-nav> 
  <mobile-nav class="mobile-only"></mobile-nav>
</ion-header>  
<ion-split-pane>
  <ion-menu type="overlay" [content]="content" class="menu-width">
    <ion-header no-border class="header-style">
      <ion-toolbar color="light">
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="side-menu-bg-color">
      <ion-list no-lines>
        <!--loops through titles to be displayed in side menu-->
        <div *ngFor="let p of pages; let i=index" (click)="toggleGroup(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}">
          <button ion-item (click)="openPage(p)" class="side-menu-bg-color">
            <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" item-left></ion-icon>
            <span class="side-menu-title">{{p.title}}</span> <span item-right class="side-menu-messages">{{p.messages}}</span>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="p.expandable != nil" item-right [name]="isGroupShown(i) ? 'ios-arrow-up' : 'ios-arrow-down'" class="expand-icon"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <!--dragula applied for drag and drop within expandable side menu options-->
          <div  id="menu-dragula-mirror">
          <div [dragula]='"movableProject"' *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
            <div *ngFor="let sub of p.expandable">
              <button ion-item (click)="goProjects()" menuClose [ngClass]="{'companyColor-one' : sub.company == 'NETS', 'companyColor-two' : sub.company == 'airBux', 'companyColor-three' : sub.company == 'Muulla'}"
                class="expandable-side-menu expandable-side-menu-bg">{{sub.company}} <span item-right class="side-menu-messages">{{sub.messages}}</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" main #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { WebListPage } from '../pages/web-list/web-list';
import { MobileListPage } from '../pages/mobileList/mobileList';
import { WeekOutlookPage } from '../pages/week-outlook/week-outlook';
import { OverduePage } from '../pages/overdue/overdue';
import { WatchingPage } from '../pages/watching/watching';
import { FavouritesPage } from '../pages/favourites/favourites';
import { ActivitiesPage } from '../pages/activities/activities';
import { ProjectsPage } from '../pages/projects/projects';
import { AssigneesPage } from '../pages/assignees/assignees';
import { FilterPage } from '../pages/filter/filter';
import { LabelPage } from '../pages/label/label';
import { DragulaService } from '../../node_modules/ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';
import { WebCalPage } from '../pages/web-cal/web-cal';
import { CalCompComponent } from '../components/cal-comp/cal-comp';
import { LeftMenuComponent } from '../components/left-menu/left-menu';
import { CommentsComponent } from '../components/comments/comments';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-menu',
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [DragulaService]
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = WebListPage;

  pages: any;
  shownGroup = null;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Inbox', component: WebListPage, icon: 'ios-filing-outline', messages: 8 },
      { title: 'Today', component: WebCalPage, icon: 'ios-sunny-outline', messages: 15 },
      { title: 'Next 7 Days', component: WeekOutlookPage, icon: 'ios-calendar-outline', messages: 45 },
      { title: 'Overdue', component: OverduePage, icon: 'ios-timer-outline', messages: 2 },
      { title: 'Watching', component: WatchingPage, icon: 'ios-eye-outline' },
      { title: 'Favourites', component: FavouritesPage, icon: 'star-outline' },
      { title: 'My Activities', component: ActivitiesPage, icon: 'heart-outline' },
      { title: 'Projects', component: ProjectsPage, icon: 'ios-folder-open-outline', expandable: [{ company: "airBux", messages: 2 }, { company: "NETS", messages: 5 }, { company: "Muulla", messages: 16 }] },
      { title: 'Assignees', component: AssigneesPage, icon: 'ios-contact', expandable: [] },
      { title: 'Filters', component: FilterPage, icon: 'ios-funnel', expandable: [] },
      { title: 'Labels', component: LabelPage, icon: 'ios-pricetag-outline', expandable: [] },
    ];

    // code for dragula drag and drop 
    this.dragulaService.setOptions('movableProject', {
      revertOnSpill: true,
    });

  }


  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }


  // code for having expandable arrows point up and down on toggle when expanding menu title
  toggleGroup(group) {
    if (this.isGroupShown(group)) {
      this.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      this.shownGroup = group;
    }
  }
  isGroupShown(group) {
    return this.shownGroup === group;
  }

  goProjects() {
    this.nav.push(ProjectsPage);
  }

}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see other peoples take on this. I can point you to the Ionic docs on Theming https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/  src/theme/variables.scss  https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/ but as to integrating i'm not sure on best way.. I had similar experience with PrimeNG

Comment: You might find this useful to see how Ionic injects styles. It doesn't answer the best way to integrate things, but will give you a feel for how Ionic does stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216030/495157 I gave an answer at the end linking to the Ionic source code..

Comment: Does Dragula provide its own CSS for the component(s) your using? Do you think you can link the relevant parts of the Dragula docs for the component(s) you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula ? https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/blob/master/dist/dragula.css ? "You'll also need to add Dragula's CSS stylesheet dragula.min.css to your application. You can find this in node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css." http://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html

Comment: I've asked in the forums for Plunker, how to setup an Ionic 3 app... How to run CLI commands like ionic generate component etc. If you want, I'll try and collaborate with you on this one. I see you are in Australia... So UK time difference might make it awkward, but happy to try stuff out. FYI: You need a Github account for Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dragula you should have included a dragula.min.css file for the default style of dragula.
And in this file you can style your html components while dragging.
You just have to put .gu-mirror in front of the css style.

For Example:

```
.gu-mirror .datetime-md{
padding:6px;
}
.gu-mirror .select-md{
    padding:5px;
}
```