# Ionic CSS classes assignment

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, sass

I’m styling my app. Familiar with the basic theming components, SASS etc... But one thing that stands out and it not making sense is why when I preview the source in a running app how lots of extra CSS classes are added. I’m my case I am simply trying to change the menu header background. In my app.html file I have;

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Which translates to;

```
    <ion-header class="header header-md">
        <ion-toolbar class="toolbar toolbar-md">
<div class="toolbar-background toolbar-background-md" ng-reflect-klass="toolbar-background" ng-reflect-ng-class="toolbar-background-md"></div><div class="toolbar-content toolbar-content-md" ng-reflect-klass="toolbar-content" ng-reflect-ng-class="toolbar-content-md">
          <ion-title class="title title-md"><div class="toolbar-title toolbar-title-md" ng-reflect-klass="toolbar-title" ng-reflect-ng-class="toolbar-title-md">Menu</div></ion-title>
        </div></ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
```

I see that there seems to be a pattern of 'ion-element' translating to 'element element-md'. But it gets a little strange for elements such as 'ion-toolbar' as this adds a div

```
<div class="toolbar-background toolbar-background-md" ng-reflect-klass="toolbar-background" ng-reflect-ng-class="toolbar-background-md">
```

I’d like to understand how this translation process works for me I'd like to create some tidy CSS as its looking a bit unwieldy to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ion-header** is an angular directive (as is **ion-toolbar**). Directives can have an associated HTML template and javascript. The extra classes are added by the javascript that belongs to each directive. The code below demonstrates an angular directive where a class is added to the original element. If you inspect the results you can also see an extra div being added - that is the result of the directive's template being added to the DOM.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("soDemo", []);
  app.directive("soDirective", SoDirective);

  function SoDirective() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      link: link,
      template: '<div class="content">My directive contents</div>'
    };
    return directive;
    ///////////////////
    function link(scope, element) {
      element.addClass('sample-class');
      
      console.log(element.html());
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.sample-class {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="sample" ng-app="soDemo">
  <so-directive></so-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: aha! I'm familier with the basics of Angular so all this now makes perfect sense, great answer and code example, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Header Ionic API Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Header/), for `<ion-header>` you'll see there are Sass variables for 3 platforms - the abbreviation to right of colon is used to target platform specific styling rules:

- iOS : ios
- Material Design (default if in browser like Chrome) :md
- Windows Platform : wp

Plaform specific styles confirm that [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/)

When you do `ionic serve --lab` you have the option to choose platform and get a feel for the default files render.

When you want to target CSS for specific platforms, then the 
nomenclature is:
 `[<elementname>-<platform-abbreviation>]`

Here's a [more complete list of SASS variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) for the different Ionic Components.
In your project there is a **themes/variables.scss** where you can use those values.
You can define your own SCSS variables like `$my-padding:5px;` in here and then use that in your custom component CSS, and consequently have that constant declared once and you can globally apply.
So my-component.scss has

```
[ion-item] {
   padding: $my-padding;
}
```

The toolbar source folder is [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/src/components/toolbar).

[toolbar-header.ts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toolbar/toolbar-header.ts) contains the `@Directive` selector 'ion-header' for `<ion-header>` Typescipt class name: **Header**

[toolbar.ts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toolbar/toolbar.ts) contains the `@Directive` selector 'ion-toolbar' for `<ion-toolbar>` Typescript class name: **Toolbar**

There are scss files for the platforms..

- [toolbar.ios.scss](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toolbar/toolbar.ios.scss)
- [toolbar.md.scss](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toolbar/toolbar.md.scss)
- [toolbar.wp.scss](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toolbar/toolbar.wp.scss)

They seem to import:

- [ionic.globals.scss](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/themes/ionic.globals.scss)

Furthermore you can configure things in your app-module.ts.

```
@ngModule({
 ....
 imports: [
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { // settings object
     iconMode: 'ios', // all platforms globally use ios icons
     tabsHighlight: true, // seems to work only on android
     platforms: {
        android: { tabsPlacement: 'top' // platform specific
        }
                }
   })
```

This should give you an insight